# Grab results from a php exec() while the command is still running?

Tags: php, exec

When I run an `exec` from PHP like so:

```
$result = exec('command');
```

The results from this will be stored in `$result`. But in my current case, my command can take a few minutes and outputs results as it is running. Is there a way I can get output while it is running? I know that the `passthru` method will output the results to be browser, but I actually want it directly.

Comment: use CGI instead of PHP, possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should take a look at [proc_open](http://php.net/proc_open)

After making the output stream non-blocking (with `stream_set_blocking`), you can read from it whenever you want without having your PHP-code blocked.

-Edit-
If you use

```
$result = exec('command > /path/to/file &');
```

It will run in the background and you can read the output in /path/to/file

Answer (score 5):

Maybe not the best way to do it (but worked for me):

```
<?php

$cmd = "ping 127.0.0.1 -c 5"; //example command

$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"), 
    1 => array("pipe", "w"), 
    2 => array("pipe", "a")
);

$pipes = array();

$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, null);

echo "Start process:\n";

$str = "";

if(is_resource($process)) {
    do {
        $curStr = fgets($pipes[1]);  //will wait for a end of line
        echo $curStr;
        $str .= $curStr;

        $arr = proc_get_status($process);

    }while($arr['running']);
}else{
    echo "Unable to start process\n";
}

fclose($pipes[0]);
fclose($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[2]);
proc_close($process);

echo "\n\n\nDone\n";

echo "Result is:\n----\n".$str."\n----\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

specify second argument

```
exec('command', $result);
```

> If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be
>   filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing
>   whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array. Note that if
>   the array already contains some elements, exec() will append to the
>   end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements,
>   call unset() on the array before passing it to exec().

Comment: Thanks but from my understanding this still requires the exec to finish completely before I can get the output. I'm specifically looking to get the output while the command is running so that I can update a progress bar.

Comment: @Zenox: ah. in that case, it's not possible. PHP is not async

Comment: async is a more of a programming approach then a language feature, it can be [achieved in PHP](https://github.com/elazar/asynchronous-php), however ***parallel*** is a different story - for that you have to compile a special version of PHP with ZTS, then you can leverage the `parallel` package - https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.parallel.php

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to achieve what you need using [`passthru()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) combined with [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php). Not sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

For whomever it may help, I've used Eddie's answer and modified it for my purposes (outputting a MySQL dump file without flooding the server's RAM)

```
$dumpCommand = "mysqldump --skip-lock-tables -u $dbuser -p$dbpasswd $dbname";
$dumpFileName = 'backup_'.$dbname.'-'.date('Ymd-Hi').'.sql';

$descriptorSpec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"), 
    1 => array("pipe", "w"), 
    2 => array("pipe", "a")
);

$pipes = array();

$process = proc_open($dumpCommand, $descriptorSpec, $pipes, null, null);

if(!is_resource($process)) {
    die('Unable to start process');
}

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$dumpFileName.'"');

do {
    echo fgets($pipes[1]); // Will wait for EOL
    $arrStatus = proc_get_status($process);
} while($arrStatus['running']);

fclose($pipes[0]);
fclose($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[2]);
proc_close($process);
```