# VC and PHP interlinking

Tags: php, visual-c++

I want to link VC++ and PHP in my code so that I can control and instruct my VC++ software at remote computer from my computer. For example: If I have to checkdisk at computer at my home using my software by instructing it through web application build in php

Please help me out!

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are the php functions [exec](http://php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php) and [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/de/function.shell-exec.php)
you can use those to execute a command line application and retrieve the output

Comment: it is possible to pass input and get output simultaneously like if I have to see the progress in percentage from 0 - 100 in graph form, can I do the same?

Comment: yes, see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703278/grab-results-from-a-php-exec-while-the-command-is-still-running