# PHP - Process output of system command - Long-running process

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I want to keep tabs on the cpu usage of my server. I want to craft a PHP CLI script (not CGI).

I'm going to run `top` in batch mode, so it will update every five seconds and show the highest-CPU-consuming processes. I could just pipe the output to `tee` in a `screen` session, but I don't care to store this excess of information. I just want to store the pertinent data where the top process is consuming more than, say, 20% CPU.

So here's what I'm hoping is possible to accomplish: Can PHP run the `top` command and then also process its output in realtime? `top` is producing a continuous stream of data (new data every 5 seconds). Can PHP process the data *before* the `top` process terminates?

Thanks for your consideration!

Edit: I was getting nowhere with Google, until *just after* posting this question. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17423664/3268008
It's 10 years old, so is it still relevant code?

Comment: Yes, the APIs are still the same.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks! Time to chase another tangent of PHP so I can learn it ;)